# SwiftUI - text moving outside of bottom panel

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view which I am presenting as a bottom panel using sheet and applying presentation detents to it. I have a header view which looks similar to what's on Apple Maps info card. I do have top padding on it, but when text gets longer and is wrapped, I see the text keeps moving up and eventually moves out of panel from top if the text becomes extremely long.

How can I prevent the text from moving up and always honor the top padding?

Note: I have too much code in my view so just sharing the piece of code where the issue is, but if more code is needed, then please comment. Thanks!

***Code:***

```
struct ContentView: View {
 
    @State var detent: PresentationDetent = .small

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.headerView
            self.buttonView
            self.detailsListView
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing, .top], 16.0)
        .background(Color.lightGray)
        .presentationDetents([.small, .large], selection: detent)
        .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
    }

    private var headerView: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Image(system: "pencil.circle").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 52.0, height: 52.0).padding(.leading, 5.0)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("This is a very long title that wraps on next line.").font(.title2).bold().fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                if !subtitleText.isBlank {
                    Text("This is a very very very very very very very long subtitle that wraps on next line.").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(Color.systemLightSecondary).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
            }.padding(.leading, 2.0)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Image(system: "x.circle").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 23).foregroundColor(Color.gray).padding(.leading, 3.0).padding(.top, 0.0)
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 7.0)
        .padding(.bottom, viewModel.hideButton ? 3.0 : 8.0)
    }

    private var buttonView: some View {
        Button { buttonAction() } label: {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Image(system:"figure.walk").font(.caption.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.white).padding(.top, 13.0)
                    Text("Directions").font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.white).padding(.bottom, 13.0)
                }
                Spacer()
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60.0, height: 60, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .font(.headline)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }

    private var detailsListView: some View {
        // List with additional details
    }
}
```

***Screenshot of the issue (highlighted in RED) and what's expected (highlighted in GREEN):***

[image]
[image]

Edit: This is happening because of the button height. If I remove the button or remove height of it, then the contents doesn't move up. I have added code for the button.. any idea why would button height move the contents up instead of down?

Comment: I've experimented with your code a bit and, regarding this question: "why would button height move the contents up instead of down?", contents of a `.sheet()` seem to be centered vertically. Once the contents height exceeds the height of the sheet, some of it is pushed outside the vertical bounds and clipped. The button in the "wrong" example is also pushed outside bounds but is still visible due to the safe area insets.

Comment: As for the subtitle text pushing everything outside the bounds, this is because of this line: `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)`. It prevents this text from truncating. You can use `.lineLimit()` to limit the number of lines depending on the detent size, or a construct like this: `Color.clear.overlay(alignment: .top) { Text("...").fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) }.clipped()`

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted or if you need an explanation of why it works. Good luck!

Comment: Ahh.. this explains the behavior well. I will try using the overlay construct and see if it works.. With lineLimit I am noticing inconsistent behavior and have read that's it's not stable hence I went with fixedSize. Thanks!